# PayPal .Net library. Disallow certain credit card types during payment process

Tags: .net, paypal

After following [this tutorial](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/quickstart/environment/) on how to setup the PayPal payment process in my .Net application, one of the features that we want to implement is the ability to disallow certain credit card types like American Express or Discover cards.

I can't find anything in the documentation on how to do this and googling around hasn't shown me anything either. Is this type of functionality possible? Or even legal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't link to a particular integration method

But assuming you're speaking of something like normal PayPal Checkout: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/

You actually aren't provided with any information (much less control) over whether the customer pays with their bank account, PayPal credit, PayPal balance, Venmo, Visa, MasterCard, Discover, American Express, Maestro, JCB, China UnionPay, or any of the many other alternative payment methods.

All you know is that you received a payment to your account; PayPal does the processing and keeps customers' billing information private by design

Comment: I was using checkout yes, I thought that there might be a way to disable certain payments types in the developer dashboard or something, but from you're saying it doesn't look like it. Thank you